# Why aren't word processing program documents stored as plaintext?

Tags: encoding

Whenever an MS word (or LibreOffice or other word processor) document is opened in its respective program, the words appear normally on the page, but when the document is opened in a text editor, most of it is Unicode gibberish.

I can understand why the document might have some parts that aren't legible, like bullet points or metadata, but why isn't at least some of the content stored as plaintext? Does every letter get encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last format docx of Microsoft Word is an xml with plain text compressed with zip. You can unzip the file by renaming docx to zip and then open the file with a notepad. So it is stored partially as plain text just compressed.

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is probably a branding thing.  If you want you can import it to a Text File.

If you go to File > Export > Change File Type > Plain Text (*.txt), you can export the document there.